# Tesselate only selected faces

Tags: add-on, edit-mode, faces

I'm looking for a way to tesselate only my selected faces using the [Tissue](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/mesh/tissue.html) add-on. How can I achive this?

[image]

Comment: why not just select the faces you want to tesselate then press `p` *> separate by selection*? Then you can tesselate and then join it back with its original object using `Ctrl+J` and then select all with `A` *>Merge By Distance*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Among (many) other things, *Tissue > Tesselate* allows you to pick your tiling-element by material. The association is made by name.

[image]

Above, the blue-and-green base object has 2 materials, named (blue) 'T1' and (green) 'T2'. The tiling-elements have the same names: (yellow object) 'T1' and  (red object) 'T2'. The tiles are assigned to faces with the corresponding material name, as shown on the left.

The initial invocation is via this button:

[image]

.. and can introduced to an existing tesselation via this setting in the 'Data' tab, 'Tissue' panel:

[image]

A face assigned with a material whose name does not match any object will not be tiled... but for consistency, personally, I prefer to be explicit.

Comment: Thank you very much I've forgotten that this exists.